# .Net Maui-Can't set my appicon as the push notification small icon for Android

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, maui, appicon

I am trying to implement firebase push notifications on my .Net Maui app. When  I try to set my appicon as the smallicon of the notification it is not recognised.[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5R2k6.png)

This is working in xamarin.forms. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: have you found your solution ? i still cant change the notification icon

Answer (score 0):

You can put the image in the `Resources/Images` folder in the MAUI. It is different between the Maui and Xamarin. Then change the wrong code to `Resource.Drawable.appicon`.

```
   var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MainActivity.ChannelID)
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.appicon)
                .SetContentTitle(title)
                .SetContentText(messageBody)
                .SetChannelId(MainActivity.ChannelID)
                .SetPriority((int)NotificationPriority.High);
    
    var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
    notificationManager.Notify(MainActivity.NotificationID, notificationBuilder.Build());
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Gaungyu. Even when I try this the namespace Projectname.Resource.Drawable is not getting recognised. I am using .net 8 jfyi.

Comment: Do not need to add the `projectname`, just `Resource.Drawable.appicon`.

Comment: I didn't add the projectname but when I type Resource in my code it refers to 'projectname.Resource'. Can you please tell me which namespace does Resource.Drawable. appicon belong to?

Comment: If you change that name, you also have to rename the android:icon and android:iconRound property in the AndroidManifest. Please check if you have changed the property.